# Puppeteer - How to remove script tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've been looking into Puppeteer, and am able to get the innerHTML, however, this can also contain `<script>` content which I would like removed.

How do I achieve this?

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.example.com');

console.log(await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML));
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```js
const innerHTML = await page.evaluate(() => {
  for (const script of document.body.querySelectorAll('script')) script.remove();
  return document.body.innerHTML;
});
```